# Flex image source concatenated

Tags: image, apache-flex

Within Flex, I am trying to concatenated the name of an image within a pathname. Preferably, I would like to do this by embeding, but if it will only work without embeding then I will go that route. My code looks like this for embeded:

```
<s:Image id="loader1" source="@Embed(source="'/images/'+{data.photo}+'.png'")"/>
```

Where my code for unembeded looks like this:

```
<s:Image id="loader1" source="'/images/'+{data.photo}+'.png'"/>
```

When I code the direct pathname I am able to get the picture. That code looks like this:

```
<s:Image id="loader1" source="@Embed(source='/images/2008-2011.png')"/>
```

Comment: even if it looks tricky, there are some way to do that: http://flexpletives.blogspot.fr/2010/02/dynamically-showing-embedded-images-in.html

Comment: @ZNK-M, I decided to go with the method I mentioned to skovalyov below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible, because embedding is compile time and by metadata you specify the explicit path to the image. While your data.photo variable gets its value during runtime. I would recommend you to embed all the images you need upfront and declare a hash table, where all possible values for data.photo are keys and embedded images are values. This would help you to implement a binding in a very similar way to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @skovalyov. Since I am using ArcGIS API for Flex, I'Ve decided to hardcode the paths within the database. I know this is not the most ideal route, but it appears this will solve the issue. Then I can just call the images using `<s:Image source="{data.Photo}"/>`, I think. Does this sound correct? Thanks again.

Comment: It depends on what you are aiming for. Dynamic binding will work fine, but your images will load runtime. Embedding that you mentioned in original post will embed images into the resulted compiled SWF. Both methods have advantages and disadvantages. For static unchanged assets embedding is usually better. For dynamic visual content runtime loading is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and providing an easy to understand response.